# How do I reinstall github desktop for Windows?

Tags: github, github-for-windows, github-desktop

I'm trying to do a fresh install of GitHub Desktop for Windows, as I installed with the wrong settings. I uninstall it through Programs and Features. However, when I reinstall it, it skips the part where I get to chose the settings, and just installs with my old data still there (same repos, already logged in). How do I completely remove it and start again?

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the Gitter folder located at: C:\Users\yourusernamehere\AppData\Local\Programs\Gitter

Comment: Looks like it gets stored in 
`C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\GitHub Desktop` nowadays.